# Overwriting 'require' leads to "no such file to load

Tags: ruby

I deleted my original post, because I can now simplify my question with a very short program:

```
 ## a.rb
 require 'tmpdir'
```

Executing `a.rb` is fine, no error.

But if I overwrite `require` as:

```
## b.rb
module Kernel
  alias_method :original_require, :require

  def require name
    i = 1
    begin
      original_require name
    rescue LoadError => e
      puts "Failure #{i}: #{e}"
      i = i + 1
      retry if i < 3
    end
  end
end

require 'tmpdir'
```

Executing `b.rb` will get the following error:

```
Failure 1: no such file to load -- Win32API
Failure 2: no such file to load -- Win32API
/Users/chaol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p376/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:19:in `<class:Dir>': uninitialized constant Dir::Win32API (NameError)
    from /Users/chaol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p376/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chaol/Documents/ruby-workspace/Test/root/aaa.rb:9:in `require'
    from /Users/chaol/Documents/ruby-workspace/Test/root/aaa.rb:9:in `require'
    from /Users/chaol/Documents/ruby-workspace/Test/root/aaa.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Is `$LOAD_PATH` different with and without your modification?

Comment: @sawa The `retry` jumps to the top of the `begin`.

Comment: what are you requiring? You'd better add more error logs.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I just realized that. Thanks.